# Retrofit 2 Queue Waiting Size

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new to the retrofit 2 library and I am wondering: what is the maximum number of calls that can fit to the waiting queue?

Does it use PriorityBlockingQueue which is a self growing queue?

Comment: I slightly reworded your question to make it more clear, please review my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question makes me want to dig inside the `Retrofit` source code. And here is my result, this can be incorrect but I want to share. Please correct me if you found the better answer!

The code contains `maxRequests` info is [`okhttp3.Dispatcher`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Dispatcher.java) class, and they use `Deque` not `PriorityBlockingQueue`:

```
public final class Dispatcher {
    private int maxRequests = 64;
    private int maxRequestsPerHost = 5;
    ....
```

As the docs said:

> Each dispatcher uses an `ExecutorService` to run calls internally. If you supply your own executor, it should be able to run `{@linkplain #getMaxRequests the configured maximum}` number of calls concurrently.

That's mean, the maximum number of concurrently calls depends on what you do:

- if you provide your `ExcutorService` (by using [`OkHttpClient.Builder`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.java#L800)), you can set its `maxRequests` value by [`setMaxRequests`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Dispatcher.java#L78) function.
- If you don't, it uses the default its [`executorService`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Dispatcher.java#L63) with default **64** concurrently requests.

**Edit:**

More info about your question ***what is the maximum number of calls that can fit to the waiting queue?***, you can see this function code in `Dispatcher` class:

```
synchronized void enqueue(AsyncCall call) {
    if (runningAsyncCalls.size() < maxRequests && runningCallsForHost(call) < maxRequestsPerHost) {
      runningAsyncCalls.add(call);
      executorService().execute(call);
    } else {
      readyAsyncCalls.add(call);
    }
  }
```

If `runningAsyncCalls` queue size is reached `maxRequests` (concurrently requests), new `call` will be added to `readyAsyncCalls`, and this `queue` has no limit size, that means the maximum calls value will be **`Integer.MAX_VALUE`**.

Comment: You just answered  the question "How many concurrent requests can happen at the same time" not how many requests can fit inside the queue until a network thread executes it.